# Convert list boolean to list string flutter

Tags: flutter, boolean, converters

How to convert list string to list bool?

```
List<String> listString = ["true", "false, "true"]

List<bool> listBool = []
```

I have try this

```
listBool = listString.map((f)=>(f.contains("true")? listBool.add(true): listBool.add(false)));
```

my expected result is

```
listBool = [true, false, true]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
List<String> listString = ["true", "false", "true"];
List<bool> listBool = listString.map((e) => e == "true").toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using forEach method, like this:

```
    List<String> listString = ["true", "false", "true"];
    List<bool> listBool = <bool>[];
    listString.forEach((item) => item == "true" ? listBool.add(true) : listBool.add(false));
```